# vscode snippet - multiple regex transformation filepath+filename

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, regexp-replace, vscode-snippets

after 1 week of searching and try&error I'm creating this question in the hope of someone willing to help me out on this one:

My VsCode Snippet should transform the following:

```
D:\FolderX\FolderY\src\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3
```

into:

```
FOLDER1_FOLDER2_FOLDER3_FILENAMEBASE
```

Folder3 could be optional

what if come up so far is:

```
"body": [
    "${TM_DIRECTORY/^.+(src\\\\)(.*)$/${2:/upcase}${3:/upcase}/g}_${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}",
],
```

and the result so far is:

```
FOLDER1\FODLER2\FOLDER3_FILENAMEBASE
```

so all I need to do now is change the `\` to `_` but I want that in one transformation if it's possible..
Anyone have an idea or better solution for my problem?
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
"body": [
    "${TM_DIRECTORY/^(?:.*\\\\)?src\\\\|([^\\\\]+)|(\\\\)/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}/g}_${TM_FILENAME_BASE/.+/${0:/upcase}/}",
],
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*\\\\)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then
- `src\\\\` - `src\` string
- `|` - or
- `([^\\\\]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `\`
- `|` - or
- `(\\\\)` - Group 3: a `\` char.

The `${1:/upcase}${2:+_}` replacement means that Group 1 is always returned uppercased, and if Group 2 matches (a `\` char), it is replaced with a `_` char.

The `${TM_FILENAME_BASE/.+/${0:/upcase}/}` is simplified as there is a `$0` backreference to the whole match, no need to wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group.

Comment: Hey there, until now this worked great but I just figured that in Linux there are different path characters.    
From what I've figured out so far, this should work: `(\\\\) -> (\/)`    
`${TM_DIRECTORY/^(?:.*\/)?(src\/)|([^\/]+)|(\/)/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}`    

but VSCode doesn't show the correct answer.    
Example of path:     
`~/FolderX/FolderY/src/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3`    \n
Any help? Thanks

Comment: @MarcK You need to just add `/`, this way - `^(?:.*[\\/\\\\])?src[\\/\\\\]|([^\\/\\\\]+)|([\\/\\\\])`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not directly related to question, however, it is because of the answer from [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68770129/13264506), that I managed to make my snippet work, after a couple of hours on this.

I am modifying the standard `rfce` snippet from dsznajder - ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets.

I work with the following structure in my react dev:

```
src
|--components
|----NavBar
|------index.css
|------index.jsx
```

So, when creating the functional components, I need to create them with the actual name of the folder, and not the file name. Therefore, below is the full snippet, and I created this in the custom javascriptReact snippets:

```json
{
  "reactFunctionalExportComponent": {
    "prefix": "rfce_",
    "body": [
      "import './index.css';",
      "",
      "function ${1:${TM_DIRECTORY/^(?:.*\\\\)/$1/g}}() {",
      "  return(",
      "    <div>",
      "      <h1>${1:${TM_DIRECTORY/^(?:.*\\\\)/$1/g}}</h1>",
      "    </div>",
      "  );",
      "}",
      "",
      "export default ${1:${TM_DIRECTORY/^(?:.*\\\\)/$1/g}};",
      ""
    ],
    "description": "Creates a React Functional Component with ES7 module system"
  }
}
```

The result looks like this:

```js
import "./index.css";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>NavBar</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

I have made similar changes for class components and also arrow functions.