# Vscode snippet: tranform filename to Capitalize sentence with a regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to tranform `filename-with-dashes.md` to `Filename with dashes` in a Vscode snippet

To be precise, I want to populate the field `"title"` in this snippet, from a filename similar to `firt-post-ever.md` and get `First post ever`:

```
"FrontMatter": {
    "scope": "markdown",
    "prefix": "frontmatter",
    "body": [
        "---",
        "title: '${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^([^-]*)-([^.]*).*/${1:/pascalcase} ${2:/capitalize}/}'",
        "draft: true",
[...]
```

**What I have so far**:

This regex changes `filename-with-dashes.md` to `Filename with-dashes` (← **I still need to remove the dashes in the end**):

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^([^-]*)-([^.]*).*/${1:/pascalcase} ${2:/downcase}/}
```

Resources I checked:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar
- [vscode snippet - multiple regex transformation filepath+filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769767/vscode-snippet-multiple-regex-transformation-filepathfilename)
- [VSCode Keybinding Snippet: Use TM_SELECTED_TEXT to Remove All Slashes From A Selected String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69173032/vscode-keybinding-snippet-use-tm-selected-text-to-remove-all-slashes-from-a-sel)
- [VSCode chaining regex transforms in a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507762/vscode-chaining-regex-transforms-in-a-snippet)
- [Transform and regex in Code Snippets in VSCode - Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227382/transform-and-regex-in-code-snippets-in-vscode-docs)

Unfortunately, these pages wasn't enough to find a proper answer (I can't understand the regex syntax, despite heavy effort I can't get it..) Any hint?

**Notes**:

- *only the first letter* of the whole title must be uppercase
- the filename may contain dots (example: notes-for-dev.to-update-2022.md).
  In such case *only the file extension must be stripped*

Comment: So for `notes-for-dev.to-update-2022.md` the result is `notes-for-dev.to-update-2022.` ?

Comment: Hi @Mark, the result of "`notes-for-dev.to-update-2022`" is "`Notes For Dev.to Update 2022`" with the regex reported right under "What I have so far"

Comment: You **want** the result for `notes-for-dev.to-update-2022.md` to be `Notes For Dev.to Update 2022`?

Comment: Nope, I only want the *first* letter to be capitalize: `Notes for dev.to update 2022`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a snippet that works:

```
"FrontMatter": {
    "scope": "markdown",
    "prefix": "frontmatter",
    "body": [
        "---",
        
        "title: '${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(^\\w*)|(-)/${1:/pascalcase}${2:+ }/g}'",
        
        // if other words might have caps you don't want

        "title: '${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(^\\w+)|(\\w+)|(-)/${1:/pascalcase}${3:+ }${2:/downcase}/g}'",
        
        "draft: true"
    ]
}
```

`(^\\w+)` get the first "word" in capture group 1
`(\\w+)` get the any other words in capture group 2
`(-)` get any `-` in capture group 3.

`${1:/pascalcase}` Capitalize the first letter of the first word and lowercase the rest of the letters of the first word.

`${3:+ }` If there is a group 3, add a space - thus replacing any `-`'s with spaces.

Comment: Perfect! Regex are so hard to understand, sincerely thanks!